# keep the rows and column hidden while changing row width and column height

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that change the rows height and column width of all the sheets in the workbook from row 1 and column B.
My problem is that its making all my hidden columns and rows also visible.
Please suggest as to how I shud modify the code so that it can change the column width and row height but should be kept them hidden.

```
Sub rowcolallsheetb()
  Dim exworkb As Workbook
  Dim xlwksht As Worksheet
  Dim lastrow1 As Long
  Dim lastcolumn1 As Long
  Dim firstrowDB As Long
  Dim Z As Integer

  Dim ShtNames() As String
  ReDim ShtNames(1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
  For Z = 1 To Sheets.Count
    ShtNames(Z) = Sheets(Z).Name
    Sheets(Z).Select
    lastrow1 = Sheets(Z).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastcolumn1 = Sheets(Z).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Z).Range(Sheets(Z).Cells(1, 2), Sheets(Z).Cells(lastrow1, lastcolumn1)).Select
    Selection.Cells.RowHeight = 9.4
    Selection.Cells.ColumnWidth = 11.2
  Next Z
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` to exclude the hidden cells from your action:

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Z).Range("B1", Sheets(Z).Cells(lastrow1, lastcolumn1)) _
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
'   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    .ColumnWidth = 11.2
    .RowHeight = 9.4
End With
```

You could also use

```
              'vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
With Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    .ColumnWidth = 11.2
    .RowHeight = 9.4
End With
```

But it's always recommended to avoid using the `Select` stuff in VBA.

Comment: I have used the below line

Comment: ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Z).Range(Sheets(Z).Cells(7, 2), Sheets(Z).Cells(lastrow1, lastcolumn1)).Select
      With Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

Comment: Still when I am running this macro the column width and row height is changing for all the rows and column (irrespective of hidden or not) and its opening all the hidden rows and column

Comment: I am still fine if it changes the row height and column width of hidden rows and column but it should not unhide the hidden rows and column

Comment: I bet you still wrote `Selection.Cells.RowHeight = 9.4`... remove that stuff and keep only  `.RowHeight = 9.4` and do the same for `.ColumnWidth = 11.2`. That's precisely the aim of the `With` clause. Write the lines *Exactly* as in my code.